# DB2 Isolation level for select statement

Tags: sql, database, db2, database-administration

### Do I need to put "WITH UR" for all subqueries in DB2?

I have following query. It seems it is locking tables/rows. I don't want it.

```
select * from (
     select a from table_a 
     UNIOIN
     select a from table_b) with ur;
```

Or Should I put "WITH UR" for each sub queries as like following?

```
select * from (
     select a from table_a with ur
     UNIOIN
     select a from table_b with ur) with ur;
```

Is there any tool that I can check which query has which kind of isolation level when it is executed in db?

Comment: Only the first option will work - one SQL with "with ur" at the very end. The first example is only a single SQL statement with subqueries.

Comment: You cannot have subquery-specific isolation levels. The isolation applies to the statement as a whole. There is always an implicit isolation level which can be inherited from the Db2 default, or from a connection-level specification, or from a package-level specification, or from a statement-level specification. The mechanism for finding the isolation level depends on your Db2-server operating-system platform, and sometimes also with the version of Db2. That's the reason you should *always* quote your Db2-server version and platform when asking for help.